# How do I determine the current Nodejs max heap size and increase it

Tags: node.js, angular

I have an Angular application build that is failing with Javascript heap allocation errors. How do I determine what the configured heap size is for a Nodejs process.

Then how do I increase it.

I've Googled this for an hour and just see a variety of contradictory and outdated answers and nothing definitive.

Win 10

Node 10.16.3

Answer (score 1):

Use [process.memoryUsage()](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_memoryusage) to get the heap size

To increase (Basically set)

```
node test.js --max-old-space-size=8192
```